# Most efficient way aggregator microservice can return multiple responses/results

Tags: python, http, server, client, microservices

I have a service which collects data from multiple Databases and services.
some Databases and services return their responses in different times, some faster then other.

I have a client-side that sends a request to this aggregator service and I want to return the DBs responses as fast a possible, I'll show an example.

1 MongoDB - query takes 5s
1 Oracle - query takes 1s
1 Service that computes some parameters to output - query takes 2s

My client sends a request to the aggregator service, which queries the MongoDB, the Oracle and send a requests to the last service, I'd like the aggregator will return the client the Oracle data after 1 sec, and then the service's response and then the Mongo response.

how can I achieve this in the most elegant and efficient way?

Cheers in advance

Comment: Can you show your code what you tried so far?

Comment: If you send the response separately what is the point of having an aggregator in the first place?